# Visual Studio + FreeBSD server + ssh =?

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, freebsd

I have a remote server (with FreeBSD) where I can develop software. But I would like to use Visual Studio, cause it is convenient :)

I have an ssh acceess to the server.

Is there any possibility to compile and debug with VS on that server?

Comment: This is one of those questions where "if you have to ask, you can't afford it."  It's possible, but will require a lot of setup, a lot of careful coding, and frequent and annoying hiccups as the whole thing breaks.  What language will you be using?

Comment: C++. And I understand this is not simple, but it is better to do this work and then take pleasure im developing instead of debugging using cout or smth...

Comment: @user1058588: if you want fun in Unix programming, then IMHO you're better off learning some of the Unix programming environment instead of learning to port software between MSVC and Unix. Try to install FreeBSD on a spare laptop and experiment with it.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: you can develop code locally with VS and transfer it. However, compiling that code both locally and remotely can be difficult, depending on how complex your program is, what language it's in and how careful you've been following portability standards such as ISO C and C++.

Comment: The program is very big. I am developing only a small part of it. Actually, the biggest problem is debugging, because executable file has a size of hundreds of megabytes and it also uses a lot of input data, so I have a lot of problems to develop and debug it on my own laptop. That is why I use remote server. But gdb doesn't work properly with such OS and also I personally don't like it.

Comment: @user - you should be using source control,

Answer (score 0):

Set up a samba share and just use that as the project path for the project. But you will have to run it on that machine ofcourse. I am not sure if there is remote debugging available for linux environments.